# WPF UserControl.Loaded event does not trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, loaded

In my program, when I hover over (MouseEnter event) a certain UserControl (here I use TransportOrderLineUserControl) a TransportOrderLineDetailView should be shown.

The TransportOrderLineDetailView should be placed at the bottom right of my screen. For this I need to know the ActualWidth & ActualHeight for a correct placement. Because those 2 properties need to have a value different than 0 I execute this code with the DetailView.Loaded event.

I use the exact same way for two other objects. There it works but not for the TransportOrderLineDetailView.

Code where the view is generated:

```
TransportOrderLineDetailView tolDetailView = new TransportOrderLineDetailView(new TransportOrderLineDetailViewModel(transportOrderLine)); 
window.DetailContent = tolView; 
tolView.Loaded += SetDetailViewOnUI;
```

Code-behind view:

```
public TransportOrderLineDetailView(TransportOrderLineDetailViewModel detailViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = detailViewModel;
    }
```

Method SetDetailViewOnUI:

```
 private void SetDetailPanelOnUI(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(window.DetailContentPresenter,
                                   window.grid_Root.ActualWidth - window.DetailContentPresenter.ActualWidth);
        Canvas.SetTop(window.DetailContentPresenter,
                      window.grid_Root.ActualHeight - window.DetailContentPresenter.ActualHeight);
    }
```

Example where it works well:

```
DriverDetailView driverDetailView = new DriverDetailView(new DriverDetailViewModel(driver));
window.DetailContent = driverDetailView;
driverDetailView.Loaded += SetDetailPanelOnUI;
```

More information

- window.DetailContent:

  ```
  private UserControl detailContent;

  public UserControl DetailContent
  {
      get { return this.detailContent; }
      set
      {
          this.detailContent = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("DetailContent");
      }
  }
  ```
- DetailContentPresenter:

  ```
   <Canvas Grid.RowSpan="2" x:Name="canvas_Popup_DetailView">
       <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding DetailContent}" x:Name="detailContentPresenter"/>
   </Canvas>
  ```

A test where the loaded event also is not triggered:

```
 public TransportOrderLineDetailView(TransportOrderLineDetailViewModel detailViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = detailViewModel;
        this.Loaded += test; //Test here
    }

    private void test(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
// method never executed
    }
```

Comment: I already did some research and there they say it is because InitializeComponent(); is not written. But as you can see, this is implemented in my code.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm guessing that when the Loaded event is fired, the UI hasn't been measured/arranged yet... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.
There was an error which was not thrown.

How I did find it was going in Visual Studio to Debug -> Exceptions -> Tick the possible exceptions.

Hope this will help other people having trouble with the same stuff. :)

Comment: What exception did you get?